# locking and unlocking in a multithreaded application

Tags: c, multithreading

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2
c89
```

Hello,

Decideing where I need to do locking and unlocking in a multi-thread applications.

Keeping the code snippets short. I have a global channel structure. i.e

```
typedef struct tag_channel channel_t;
struct tag_channel {....};
```

I have 3 functions that use an API to set and process the channels on its message queue.

My main thread #1 will call this function

```
apr_status_t set_ss7_channel_state(channel_t *channel)
{
    /* API call to set channel - non-blocking ASYNC call that returns immediately
       wait for event in evt_loop */
    setChanState(channel);
}
```

Event loop started in a spawned thread #2. Other functions could trigger the same channel buy putting the channel on the message queue.

```
static void* APR_THREAD_FUNC evt_loop(apr_thread_t *thd, void *data)
{
    while(is_looping) {
        /* Get event and channel from message API message queue */      
        waitevt();
        if(channel_process(channel) != TRUE) {
            /* clean up */      
        }   
    }
}
```

Process channel called from thread #2

```
apr_status_t channel_process(channel)
{
    /* process channel here based on the event
    /* lock channel */
    /* do some processing */
    /* unlock channel */
}
```

So basically the calls work like this for a single channel:

```
1) setChanState(channel) thread #1 -> puts channel on an API message queue
2) evt_loop(...) thread #2 will retrieve the event and the channel structure
3) process_channel(channel) will process the channel on thread #2
```

I am left wondering do I need to block the channel structure, as there could be other event on this channel?
I have put blocking on the channel_process.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: I don't see how you intend to use multiple threads here. Further, your question is impossible to answer as it is, because "other event on this channel" doesn't simply happen but is the result of some other code doing something that affects the channel. Without knowing more, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to block the channel structure. The point is that your Thread #1 is able to overwrite the contents of the channel structure while thread #2 is processing the last event (and the data associated with it).

There are multiple ways to synchronize this. Either by blocking thread #1 until thread #2 is finished or you can simply add sort of a critical section to the structure. Or you build your channel structure as a chain of jobs to process.

Answer (score -1):

It will depend on the contents of the channel structure and on exactly how it is delivered by setChanState and waitev.

If tag_channel does not contain references (eg pointers, file descriptors, or anything else that is indirectly something else) and setChanState/waitev deliver a copy of it to thread2 (through a pipe for instance) then you are effectively implementing the Actor Model, and getting close to implementing Communicating Sequential Processes (which is even better), and no further locking is required.

Otherwise you'll have to have mutexes to protect either the channel structure itself, or the things indirectly referred to by it.

Comment: I'd say it's not only if tag_channel does contain references that you have to protect the structure. Even if it's a bunch of related integer values you'll suffer from inconsitency if the producer thread will start to change the values while the consumer thread is still running.

Comment: @junix, your comment is written in ignorance of the content of tag_channel or its use. The original question makes references to message queues, and it is entirely possible that the actor model (or even better CSP) is being used (possibly accidentally) by the original poster. If you don't know what those are I suggest you look them up, they're useful.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I ignored the content of tag_channel - Or better: I did not make any assumptions on it's content. As there is no information available about that topic, I don't think it's safe to make assumptions here. It's also not clear whether the OP implements CSPs or if he wants to implement the actor model. Further it's not clear if the OP passes the channel information to thread #2 while thread #1 still keeps a reference to it or not. Given these uncertainties I added a comment to your post as I don't think that your answer fits "all circumstances".

Comment: @junix, nor did I. Exactly how does the last piece of my post, "Otherwise you'll have to have mutexes to protect either the channel structure itself, or the things indirectly referred to by it" not cover all circumstances in any way less than your own contribution?

Comment: Seems like the last sentence in your post escaped my attention. Sorry for that. But may I suggest, that you reorder the condition for omitting the protection? Because in my opinion, the main argument to omit protection is the fact that a copy is delivered, not that no references are in the structure. I'd handle this facette seperately as there are different ways to cope with that too. (proper serialization for example)

Comment: @junix, No worries, thank you for your reply. However, I am perfectly content with the order of my post. Given that the original question is lacking detail we are all condemned to having to answer with if-then-otherwise...